# Как сделать текст поверх родительского блока при помощи z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

`.events_point_hovers` располагается над списком и служит для вывода уникальных изображений поверх при наведении на пункт списка.

Сейчас эти картинки перекрывают текст, как сделать `z-index` для текста выше родительского `.events_point`?

[image: .events_point_hovers перекрывает текст]

```css
.events_point {
  z-index: 19;
}

.one.events_point:hover ~ .events_point_hovers {
  z-index: 20;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="one events_point">Пункт 1</div>
<div class="two events_point">Пункт 2</div>
<div class="three events_point">Пункт 3</div>
<div class="events_point_hovers></div>
```

Comment: Выгрузите пожалуйста код на codesandbox.io codepen.io что пожно было больше понять проблему

Comment: `z-index` не работает без указания `position: relative` или `position: absolute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) работает только для элементов с заданной [позицией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) отличной от `static`, что бы не нарушать естественное flow Вашего документа можно воспользоваться значением `relative` что бы свойство z-index заработало:

```css
.events_point {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 19;
}

.one.events_point:hover ~ .events_point_hovers {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="one events_point">Пункт 1</div>
<div class="two events_point">Пункт 2</div>
<div class="three events_point">Пункт 3</div>
<div class="events_point_hovers></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Окей, я подобрался к натяжке макета на WordPress и понял, что моя вёрстка совершенно не подходит для правильного вывода. Спасибо за подсказку про связь z-index и position.

Я разбил строку на 3 части — вывод заголовка, блок с заливкой и тенью и изображение.

```
<div class="events_list">
    
    <div class="events_list_card_text" onclick="location.href='#'">
        Пункт #1
    </div>

    <div class="events_list_card card card-shadow"></div>

    <img src="...">

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
</div>
```

Они так и выводятся через вордпресс по очереди, с добавлением нового пункта прибавляются 3 блока, а после них в самом конце идёт clearfix, сейчас объясню, зачем:

```
.events_list_card_text {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 5.208vw;
    margin-bottom: -5.208vw;
    z-index: 22;
}
.events_list_card {
    float: left;
    z-index: 20;
}
.events_list > img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 21;
}
```

Таким образом картинка всегда строится от начала родительского блока, и находится между текстом и блоком c бекграундом и тенью. Clearfix думаю всем известная штука :)